# Why did they separate Fate/Zero and Fate/Stay Night UBW into two season

Tags: fate-stay-night, fate-zero

Usually anime will be completed in a single season while second season is a sequel or prequel. But Fate/Stay Night UBW and Fate/Zero aired the first 12 episodes on first season and continued the next episode in the next season. Was there any reason why they do that?

Comment: Probably because of financial reasons, http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/22477/why-does-anime-air-in-4-seasons-per-year-of-13-episodes

Comment: @Aʟᴀɢᴀʀᴏs Nothing in the post you linked appears to address the particular question of why shows would be specifically split-cour (as UBW and F/Z were) as opposed to two consecutive cours.

Comment: I heard that in the case of Fate Zero, they wanted to keep the anime's high animation quality. So they needed to spend more time per episode to meet their quality standard. Because of that, they had to stop broadcasting for a while (since that would've given them only 1 week per episode), and therefore it was split into a second season.

Comment: i would have rathered they did that, means they aren't condensing the story. ~120 minute film VS ~24 x ~20 minutes episodes